# how to hide space area of image when image is null

Tags: react-native

[image]

i am making a comment section so i want to hide image area if image is null 
and if image source is available then show the image content
 and used condition if but still the same issue image is loading but the space area is an issue how to fix please let me know i am new to react-native

and used many many reference but still the same issue

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  BackHandler
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Icon, Header, Left, Body, Right, Segment, Button } from 'native-base'
import ImageLoad from 'react-native-image-placeholder';


export default class CommentScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[
        {id:1, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png", name:"Frank Odalthh",    comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor." , ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
        {id:2, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png", name:"John DoeLink",     comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor." , ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
        {id:3, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png", name:"March SoulLaComa", comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
        {id:4, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", name:"Finn DoRemiFaso",  comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
        {id:5, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png", name:"Maria More More",  comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
        {id:6, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png", name:"Clark June Boom!", comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl: null },
        {id:7, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png", name:"The googler",      comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl: null},
      ]
    }
  }
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

backPressed = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
    return true;
}
   static navigationOptions = { header: null }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.root}
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.separator}/>
          )
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>{
          return item.id.toString();
        }}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          const Notification = item.item;
          return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: Notification.image}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.content}>
                <View style={styles.contentHeader}>
                  <Text  style={styles.name}>{Notification.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.time}>
                    9:58 am
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <Text rkType='primary3 mediumLine'>{Notification.comment}</Text> 
                <View>

            <ImageLoad style={{width:150, height:140}}  source={{uri: Notification.ImageUrl}}/>
</View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default image using defaultSource prop or in case there is no url.

Or you can try this for not rendering it:

```
{Notification.ImageUrl? <ImageLoad style={{width:150, height:140}}  source={{uri: Notification.ImageUrl}}/> : null}
```

assuming the Notification.image is null when there is no image.

**EDITED**
your code with what iv'e suggested. notice that there is a comment out and no style. but it is working.
cheers

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TouchableOpacity,
Image,
ScrollView,
FlatList,
BackHandler
} from 'react-native';
// import { Container, Content, Icon, Header, Left, Body, Right, Segment, Button } from 'native-base'
import ImageLoad from 'react-native-image-placeholder';


export default class CommentScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   data:[
     {id:1, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png", name:"Frank Odalthh",    comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor." , ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
     {id:2, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png", name:"John DoeLink",     comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor." , ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
     {id:3, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png", name:"March SoulLaComa", comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
     {id:4, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", name:"Finn DoRemiFaso",  comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
     {id:5, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png", name:"Maria More More",  comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl:"https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"},
     {id:6, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png", name:"Clark June Boom!", comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl: null },
     {id:7, image: "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png", name:"The googler",      comment:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",  ImageUrl: null},
   ]
 }
}
componentWillMount() {
 BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

backPressed = () => {
 this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
 return true;
}
static navigationOptions = { header: null }

render() {
 return (
   <FlatList
     style={styles.root}
     data={this.state.data}
     extraData={this.state}
     ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
       return (
         <View style={styles.separator}/>
       )
     }}
     keyExtractor={(item)=>{
       return item.id.toString();
     }}
     renderItem={(item) => {
       const Notification = item.item;
       return(
         <View style={styles.container}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
             <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: Notification.image}}/>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <View style={styles.content}>
             <View style={styles.contentHeader}>
               <Text  style={styles.name}>{Notification.name}</Text>
               <Text style={styles.time}>
                 9:58 am
               </Text>
             </View>
             <Text rkType='primary3 mediumLine'>{Notification.comment}</Text>
             <View>
             {Notification.ImageUrl? <ImageLoad style={{width:150, height:140}}  source={{uri: Notification.ImageUrl}}/>: null}

</View>
           </View>
         </View>
       );
     }}/>
 );
}
}

const styles = {};
```

Comment: showing error invariant violation <Text> string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Comment: Have you imported all the components you are using?

Comment: Use the code as I suggested. I will create one with yours aswell and add it.